# How Can I create a multidimensional character array in Groovy/Grails dynamically from using CsvReader

Tags: arrays, csv, grails, multidimensional-array, groovy

I'm trying to def a multidimensional array from reading in a content from a CSV file, here is my code:

```
//this doesn't work START
def csvData = [][]
//this doesn't work END

    file.inputStream.toCsvReader([skipLines: 1]).eachLine {  tokens ->

        if(tokens[0] ==~ valid){
            numbersToProcess.add(tokens[0])
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNum; i++) {
                dataToSave.add([tokens[i]]) 
            }
        }else{
            numbersFailed.add(tokens[0])
            failedLineNumbers.add(lineNumber)
        }

        lineNumber++                    
    }
```

Now because I want to build the multidimensional array dynamically I'm unsure how I do this because I can't before the .each

Answer (score 0):

With groovy you have to specify the size of at least the first element. Also arrays are not treated as list.

so you can do

```
def csvData = new Object[100][]
```

instead.

Otherwise you can just use a list of list. Your choice. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1025-Arrays for more